# Testing for div creation

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using drupal, with a chat module that creates divs for each chat. Because it's an external module, I don't want to modify the code. My question is this:

Is there a way for jquery to trigger an event if another script creates a div? Would I have to test every X seconds, or something like that?

Comment: Please post some HTML example

Comment: You could attach an event listener to a certain div, and check if something has been created in that div

Comment: If the object isn't created yet, you cant bind a listener to it.. We need to see code on how the `div` is being generated.

Comment: Actually, it's child divs being created dynamically inside a parent div. I do know the id of that parent div, so an event listener might work. I'm just not sure which one to use. I want to add an onclick to a div that I don't know the ID of. @dbaseman - I need to support IE, which means that nothing newer than the Stone Age will work correctly :P

a little more clarification: There is a parent div with a set ID. Inside that is a <ul class>, with <li class>. Nothing has ids. The div that I want to attach a handler to has a class, not an id. I hope that helps.

Comment: You should use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/). See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') {
        alert('Content added! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
    } else {
        alert('Content removed! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

With that you could check if something has been added to a certain div. So if something has been inserted in myDiv it would trigger an event which you listen to, and then take certain actions.

Comment: FWIW, mutation events are [not supported](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) by IE.

Comment: IE9 supports them – try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fragmentedreality/yRARy/1/) from my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11047724/834309) with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the new *mutation event* spec is for.  Even though it's still in the early stages, you might be able to use it depending on what browsers you need to support.

[Feature-detect: mutation-event availability in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882238/feature-detect-mutation-event-availability-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If the clients browser supports it you can do like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fragmentedreality/yRARy/1/):

```
</div>
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript: create_div();" value="create"/>
    <div id="div-area"></div>​
    <script>
    function create_div() {
        $('#div-area').append('<div class="chatdiv">new chat</div>');
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#div-area').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e, o) {
            $(e.target).css('background', 'red');
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

According to your comment you need to register to the onclick. This is what [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is for:

```
</div>
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript: create_div();" value="create"/>
    <div id="div-area"></div>​
    <script>
    function create_div() {
        $('#div-area').append('<div class="chatdiv">new chat</div>');
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#div-area div.chatdiv').live('click', function(e, o) {
            $(e.target).css('background', 'red');
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fragmentedreality/zu344/2/).

Comment: according to [link](http://api.jquery.com/live/), live() has been deprecated in favor of on()

Comment: Does it matter if I want to bind to a div or an <li>? Also, what's the purpose of e and o?

Comment: You are right. You should rather use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). As you can read in the documentation, `e` and `o` are parameters passed to the function by the event. They are - as all params in Javascript - optional but help you identify the object that caused the event to fire. I added the `on()`-stuff to the fiddle. It works, too.

Comment: And yes, you can bind to `li` instead of a `div`. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fragmentedreality/zu344/2/) for details of selecting the content.